# python web thread

Tags: python, multithreading, web

So I have a simple python cgi script. The web front end is used to add stuff to a database, and I have update() function that does some cleanup.

I want to run the update() function every time something is added to site, but it needs to be in the background. That is, the webpage should finish loading without waiting for the update() function to finish.

Now I use:

```
-add stuff to db
Thread(target=update).start()
-redirect to index page
```

The problem seems to be that python does not want to finish the request (redirect) until the update() thread is done.

Any ideas?

Comment: This might be beyond what CGI can do - you might need to look at a more advanced setup like WSGI. (I could be wrong, though)

Answer (score 1):

> That is, the webpage should finish loading without waiting for the update() function to finish

CGI has to wait for the process -- as a whole -- to finish.  Threads aren't helpful.

You have three choices.

1. `subprocess`.  Spawn a separate "no wait" subprocess to do the update.  Provide all the information as command-line parameters.
2. `multiprocessing`.  Have your CGI connect place a work request in a Queue.  You'd start a separate listener which handles the update requests from a Queue.
3. `celery`.  Download Celery and use it to manage the separate worker process that does the background processing.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain how to implement option 1. ?

Comment: This seems perfectly clear. http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-the-os-spawn-family  There are numerous stack overflow questions about sub processing.  Did you try "Search"?  What **specific** questions do you have?

Comment: @breez: "subprocess doesn't work on Windows".  (a) False.  (b) Begin with Search.  (c) If you need help making subprocess work, ask a separate question.

Comment: I think Thomas K up above is right, that this is more than CGI can do. When I said that subprocess doesn't work I meant that it executes the process but it still blocks.

Comment: @breez: Since you haven't provided any code, it's not possible to see what you've done wrong.  (b) Search for "subprocess without waiting".  Really.  It's in the upper right corner.  Do it now.  (c) If **None** of those answers can provide you the way to spawn a subprocess with no waiting, then you must ask a new question.  I can repeat this advice again, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

- you could add a database trigger to update db in response to an event e.g., if a specific column has changed
- start a subprocess e.g., `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, '-c', "from m import update; update()"])`. It might not work depending on your cgi environment
- or just touch `update` file to be picked up by an `inotify` script to run necessary updates in a separate process
- switch to a different execution environment, e.g., some multithreaded wsgi-server
- as a heave-weight option you could use `celery` if it is easy to deploy in your environment